# Is it faster to use one for-loop or use multiple built-in methods?

Tags: javascript, performance

So I was recreating the -Sigma function in Javascript in two different ways and was wondering, which one of the methods is faster:

```js
function capitalSigma(start, end, func) {
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) {
    sum += func(i);
  }
  return sum;
}

function (start, stop, func) {
  return Array.from({length: (stop - start) + 1}, (_, i) => start + i).map(x => func(x)).reduce((a, b) => a + b)
}

var forLoopMethod = capitalSigma(1, 10, x => x ** 2)

var builtInMethod =  (1, 10, x => x ** 2)

console.log(forLoopMethod)
console.log(builtInMethod)
```

However, I'm unsure which will run faster, since with the built-in method, there would have to be two "passes" by both the `map` and the `reduce`.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: @Bergi I didn't ask anybody, I answered it myself. I just found it really interesting and wanted to maybe help "newbies" asking the same question.

Comment: I saw that (after reading the question and posting the comment), but I think the comment still applies to the question.

Comment: The map and reduce combination force extra unneeded iterations. Why would you use both? This is an apples to oranges comparison

Comment: @charlietfl Please take a loop at the answer, I corrected myself there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function which uses built-in methods can actually be written in even fewer bytes/methods:

```js
function (start, stop, func) {
    return Array.from({length: (stop - start) + 1}, (_, i) => start + i).reduce((a, b) => a + func(b))
}
```

After doing some testing in multiple environments with multiple sizes of both inputs and iterations, I can safely say that the method using the for-loop is between 3 and 20 times faster than the built-in methods one.

My code for testing looked something like this:

```js
function capitalSigma(start, end, func) {
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) {
    sum += func(i);
  }
  return sum;
}

function (start, stop, func) {
  return Array.from({
    length: (stop - start) + 1
  }, (_, i) => start + i).reduce((a, b) => a + func(b))
}

var iterations = 100000;

console.time("For-Loop Variant")

for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
  capitalSigma(1, 100, n => n ** 2)
}
console.timeEnd("For-Loop Variant")

console.time('Built-in Method Variant');
for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
    (1, 100, n => n ** 2);
};
console.timeEnd('Built-in Method Variant')
```

I tested my code in

- [Google Chrome DevTools](https://www.google.com/chrome/)
- [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/)
- [Deno](https://deno.land/)
- [Apple Safari DevTools](https://www.apple.com/safari/)

All testing was done on an [Intel MacBook Air](https://github.com/gurkensaas/gurkensaas/blob/main/README.md).

#### Now the question is, why is that?

My hunch is, that while the built-in methods method has a lot more one-liner satisfaction, it has to create an array in memory while the other one doesn't.

Doing some other performance tests shows that environments above, which struggle with the built-in methods method, also struggle with creating a lot of Arrays in a short amount of time.

The ratio with the initial function isn't quite as ratio between creating an Array and a number though, so I the `Array.prototype.reduce` function is definitely more optimized than a for-loop.

Here are some of the ratios I found in different Javascript environments. The numbers created were 6-digits long and the Arrays created were 100 elements long (Both of which are expected when inputting the values for all square numbers from 1 to 100 summed up.)

- Node: The for-loop method is ~40 faster than the built-in methods method and creating a Number is ~500 times faster than creating an Array.
- Google Chrome DevTools: The for-loop method is ~30 faster than the built-in methods method and creating a Number is ~50 times faster than creating an Array.
- Deno: The for-loop method is ~40 faster than the built-in methods method and creating a Number is ~500 times faster than creating an Array.
- Apple Safari DevTools: The for-loop method is ~4 faster than the built-in methods method and creating a Number is ~400 times faster than creating an Array.

<sup>All of those results are very rough because performance depends on so many things.</sup>